# Handling navigations to the url inside the webview in react native

Tags: react-native

Actually I have a webview in react native and I am trying to open a url from that webview.Once the URL is loaded on pressing the bacǩ buttton it should navigate to previous page.How to navigate back to the webview page?

Comment: Post some code and we can advise.

Answer (score 0):

There's an option that you can try with is to have your `webView` inside a `Modal` that way you can control `onBackPress`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reference of Webview and call goBack on that reference

```
<WebView
     ref={ref => {
     if (!ref) {
         return;
     }
     this.webview = ref;
}}
/>



this.webview.goBack();
```